# Como fazer um botão mostrar e esconder uma DIV ao mesmo tempo trocar o seu próprio texto com JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Sou iniciante no mundo do javascript. Eis um pouco de contexto do meu problema:
Estou desenvolvendo uma lista com projetos que montei no codepen. Para cada item da lista criei um botão com o intuito de só revelar o código "embedado" do codepen, contido numa tag div, quando clicado e para isso coloquei um  `onclick` no botão. Até aí não tive problema, pois consegui alterar o CSS através do JS, escondendo ou mostrando a DIV quando clicado. Porém estou tentando fazer o texto do botão alterar de "Preview" antes de clicado para "Fechar" depois de clicado.

Ou seja, quero trocar o `textContent` da minha tag button a cada clique que eu der no botão para ver a preview, ou fechá-la.

Eis um pouco do que fiz:
HTML:

```
    <p> Conversor de Moedas <button id="preview-btn" class="mostrar-projeto" onclick="mostrarProjetoConversor()"> Preview </button> </p>
```

Javascript:

```
function mostrarProjetoConversor() {
  var mostrarProjetoConversor = document.getElementById("projeto-conversor")
  
   mostrarProjetoConversor.classList.toggle("oculto");
  
  textoBtnAtivo();
}
```

Tentei fazer uma `var` para indicar a situação da div (aberta ou fechada), para tentar usar tal variável como referência para alterar o `textContent`, porém não obtive sucesso até então. Eis o código:

```
var situacao = ""

function textoBtnAtivo(situacao){
  var textoBtn = document.getElementById("preview-btn").textContent;
  textoBtn = " Fechar ";
  document.getElementById("preview-btn").innerHTML = textoBtn;
  
  situacao= "aberto";
}
```

Link do codepen: https://codepen.io/GBohrer/pen/BaxJLvW?editors=1111

Será que alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode tentar algo mais simples, como por exemplo:

```js
//Atribuir o elemento botão a uma variável
var btn = document.getElementById('preview-btn');
//Adicionar um evento de click ao elemento botão
btn.addEventListener('click', function() { 
   //Chamar a funcao que realiza a troca do texto passando como parametro o ID do botão
   mudarTextoBotao('preview-btn'); 
});
//função que faz a troca
function mudarTextoBotao(button_id)  {
   var text = document.getElementById(button_id).firstChild;
   text.data = text.data == "Preview" ? "Fechar" : "Preview";
}
```

Ou, se preferir, há um modo mais legível:

```js
//Atribuir o elemento botão a uma variável
var btn = document.getElementById('preview-btn');
//Adicionar um evento de click ao elemento botão
btn.addEventListener('click', function() { 
   //Chamar a funcao que realiza a troca do texto passando como parametro o ID do botão
   mudarTextoBotao('preview-btn'); 
});
//função que faz a troca
function mudarTextoBotao(button_id)  {
   var text = document.getElementById(button_id).firstChild;
   if (text.data == "Preview") {
        text.data = "Fechar";
      //codigo para exibir a div
   } else {
    text.data = "Preview";
    //codigo para ocultar a div
   }
}
```

Comment: Agradeço a resposta. Mas não consegui integrar, por falta de conhecimento mesmo, o código que você passou aos que eu já tinha para fazer funcionar. Como disse, ainda sou muito iniciante em Javascript e me perco em algumas situações.

Comment: Aqui um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/vte9xakr/

Comment: Muito obrigado!